# Problema con sub-consulta en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Tengo una base de datos en Access que posee las siguentes tablas:

Tabla **Opciones**

Columnas:

- Id_Opcion *int*
- Opcion *varchar(50)*
- Estado *(bit)*

Contiene estos datos:

[image: Contenido de la tabla Opciones]

---

Tabla **Votos**

Columnas:

- Id_Voto *int*
- Id_Opcion *int*
- Fecha *Date Time*

[image: Contenido de la tabla Votos]

---

Lo que necesito construir una consulta que obtenga la **cantidad de votos que cada opción tiene en un rango de fecha**.

Por ejemplo, si selecciono un rango de fechas entre *01/08/2016* y *31/08/2016* debería obtener un valor similar al siguiente:

[image: Resultados esperados]

Esta es la consulta que uso:

```
SELECT Opc.Opcion, (SELECT COUNT(Vts1.Id_Respuesta)
FROM Votos AS Vts1) AS [Votos],
Vts.Fecha
FROM Opcion AS Opc INNER JOIN Votos AS Vts
ON Opc.Id_Opcion = Vts.Id_Opcion
WHERE Opc.Estado = True
ORDER BY Vts.Fecha;
WHERE Opc.Estado = True AND 
(Vts.Fecha BETWEEN #01/08/2016 00:00# AND #31/08/2016 23:59#)
ORDER BY Vts.Fecha;
```

Pero los resultados no coinciden con lo esperado, además, si hay cero votos, a veces me sale este error:

> at most one record can be returned by this subquery

**¿Cómo se debe modificar la consulta para generar los resultados esperados?**

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres obtener el número de votos por opción, ¿cierto? Por otra parte, ¿qué fecha quieres que se muestre? ¿la última registrada?

Comment: @Barranka, estás en lo cierto sobre el número de votos por opción y la fecha, he actualizado la pregunta.

Comment: La fecha 08/12/2016 está fuera del rango 01/08/2016..31/08/2016, y por lo tanto no se debería incluir en el resultado esperado.

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET, tienes razón. La respuesta aceptada será la que tenga la consulta para obtener las opciones y la cantidad de votos por cada opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un `JOIN` de tus dos tablas:

```
select o.textoOpcionrespuesta as opcion
     , count(v.id) as votos
     , max(v.fechaRespuesta) as fecha_ultimo_voto
from OpcionRespuesta as o
     left join respuestas as v on o.id_opcion_respuesta = v.idOperacionRespuesta
where o.estado = true
  and (v.fechaRespuesta >= #01/08/2016# and v.fechaRespuesta < #01/09/2016#)
order by fecha_ultimo_voto;
```

Por cierto, para filtrar fechas, es una mala idea usar `BETWEEN`. Te recomiendo [leer este artículo](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) (como ves, modifiqué tu condición `WHERE` para evitar problemas).

---

Si quieres hacer esto con subconsultas, aquí está una posible solución:

```
select opcion, votos, fecha_ultimo_voto
from
    (
    select id_opcion_respuesta as id
         , textoOpcionRespuesta as opcion
    from OpcionRespuesta
    where o.estado = true
    ) as o
    left join (
        select idOperacionRespuesta as id
             , count(v.idOperacionrespuesta) as votos
             , max(fechaRespuesta) as fecha_ultimo_voto
        from respuestas
        where fechaRespuesta >= #01/08/2016# and fechaRespuesta < #01/09/2016#
        group by idOperacionRespuesta
    ) as v on o.id = v.id
order by fecha_ultimo_voto;
```

Otra observación respecto de las fechas: La forma en que Access maneja las fechas cuando las encierras en símbolos de número (`#`) depende de la configuración regional de la máquina donde estés trabajando. Para evitar problemas de ese tipo, te recomiendo usar la función `DateSerial()`:

```
#01/08/2016# --> DateSerial(2016,8,1)
^^^^^^^^^^^^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Esto puede       Esto evita el
ser ambiguo      problema de
                 ambigüedad
```

Comment: Gracias, la información acerca de _DateSerial_ para las consultas es muy útil, no lo sabía. +1

Comment: @Mauricio Access (y otros productos de Office) guardan las fechas como un número `double`, cuya parte entera es el número de días transcurridos desde el 1º de enero de 1900, y cuya parte decimal indica la fracción de día transcurrida (`0.5` equivale a `12:00:00`). `DateSerial()` devuelve un número `double` sin parte decimal. En general, puedes comparar fechas como si compararas números, lo cual hace que `DateSerial(2016,9,1)` sea equivalente a `DateSerial(2016,8,31)+1` (o, si te animas a usar fechas encerradas en signos de número, `#31/08/2016#+1`.